# What is the correct command line to execute Perl script with arguments under windows dos shell

Tags: perl

I'm trying to run a Perl script "conlleval,pl" on a datasets.txt . I've installed Active perl under windows 7 64bit. also, I've got no background in Perl,this the first time.

- Question: what is the correct command line to execute the script with the data set from the command line? and how to save the result in a "output.txt"?

Is this the correct way?

c:>Perl conllevall.pl < dataset.txt < output.txt

Note: the script and data set is in the same location, I think it is a path problem.- I've tried many tutorials but with no luck.I couldn't find any examples :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read from STDIN (using <> construct), the simplest would be

```
perl conllevall.pl dataset.txt > output.txt
```

by associating .pl extension to perl, also

```
conllevall.pl dataset.txt > output.txt
```

should work.

Comment: now the dataset crashed because I used excel to join two files how can I do that in perl is it like this: firstDataset.txt paste -d ' ' secondDataset.txt > finalDataset.txt is that correct

Comment: If the script is reading from STDIN with <>, simply try:  perl conllevall.pl set1.txt set2.txt set3.txt > output.txt

Answer (score 0):

perl conllevall.pl dataset.txt > output.txt

Comment: now the dataset crashed because I used excel to join two files how can I do that in perl is it like this: cat firstDataset.txt  ' ' secondDataset.txt > finalDataset.txt